# How to change a specific line number color in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've been wanted to do this for a while, sometimes when I have a file open I want to be able to highlight certain line numbers to a different color. For example, say my LineNr is blue, and my Current LineNr is red. Say I'm on line 25, is there anyway I can change the LineNr color of lines 28-30 to green WITHOUT leaving my current line?

Answer (score 2):

As a quick answer, if you don't mind highlighting only by groups of at most 8 lignes at once, you can use the `matchaddpos({group}, {pos})` function and create a command to apply a `highlight` group to a range of lines.

```
command! -range -nargs=1 -complete=highlight HiLine call matchaddpos(<f-args>, range(<line1>,<line2>))
```

Which you can use, for example to highlight as `'cursorline'` :

```
:28,30HiLine CursorLine
```

Note that completion applies on the argument for highlight groups.

To remove the group(s) of previously highlighted lines you could remove thoses that contains a particular line. I can't find a simpler way than to go through all `getmatches()` dicts and `matchdelete({id})` the ones that contains the line on one of their `'posX'` key :

```
function! s:RemoveMatchOnLine(line) abort
  for l:match in getmatches()
    let l:matchlines = values(filter(copy(l:match), 'v:key =~# ''pos\d\+'''))
    if index(l:matchlines, [a:line]) >= 0
      call matchdelete(l:match['id'])
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
command! -nargs=? LoLine call <SID>RemoveMatchOnLine(<q-args> ? <q-args> : line('.'))
```

Now, you can `:LoLine` to undo the highlighting on lines near the current line, or you can give it an argument to specify another line, so you don't have to move your cursor there : `:LoLine 28`.

Finally, you can set mappings :

```
nnoremap <leader>hi :HiLine CursorLine<CR>
xnoremap <leader>hi :HiLine CursorLine<CR>
nnoremap <leader>hc :<c-u>execute 'LoLine ' . v:count<CR>
```

Typing `[count]<leader>hi` in normal mode will highlight `count` lines from the cursor. And `[count]<leader>hc` will remove the highlighting on the group of line `count`.

### Addendum

We could work on larger ranges using `matchadd({group}, {pattern})`, using `\%xl` to match line `x`. Replace `call matchaddpos(...` by

```
execute 'call matchadd(<f-args>, ''\%'.<line1>.'l\(.*\n\)\+\%'.(<line2>+1).'l'')'
```

and line 2 and 3 of the function by

```
let l:a = matchlist(get(l:match,'pattern',''), '^\\%\(\d\+\)l.*\\%\(\d\+\)l$')
if !empty(l:a) && l:a[1] <= a:line && a:line <= l:a[2]
```

But for me it breaks on large ranges, I would prefer to have the first solution which seems more robust.

Comment: You might want to show usage with a range for the OP

Comment: @D.BenKnoble right, edited. Would you know why with the regex matches, it don't work well for long ranges ? e.g `:%HiLine ...` doesn't work well on the middle of the buffer, or on the top, it highlights the current view but moving down, nothing is highlighted, etc...

Comment: probably the shortcomings of using regex for highlights again